# native ad appodeal test

Tags: native-ads, appodeal

i just learn native ad with simple code and try to test run appodeal native ad. but theres no test-ad showd.

```
    Appodeal.setAutoCache(Appodeal.NATIVE, false);
    Appodeal.initialize(this, "apikey", Appodeal.NATIVE);
    Appodeal.cache(this, Appodeal.NATIVE);
    Appodeal.setNativeCallbacks(new NativeCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onNativeLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onNativeLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

        @Override
        public void onNativeFailedToLoad() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onNativeFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNativeShown(NativeAd nativeAd) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onNativeShown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNativeClicked(NativeAd nativeAd) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onNativeClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Appodeal.getNativeAds(1);
    com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.views.NativeAdViewContentStream nav_cs = this.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_view_content_stream);
    nav_cs.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
```

what is wrong? whats my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

To enable test ads in Appodeal add this line to your code:
`Appodeal.setTesting(true);`

This will enable test ads not only for the native Appodeal ads, but for all the ad types: banners, interstitials, etc.

Comment: i get error,  "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0"

Comment: I don't think this error is related to the issue described here. Does adding Appodeal.setTesting(true); cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need more time to load ads.
Usually it takes about 20 - 60 second.

In his case, you can try to use the following code: `https://pastebin.com/Wbe0V6fm`

Also, check our demo project: `https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-android-demo`
Class: `https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-android-demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/appodeal/test/AppodealWrapperAdapter.java`